# React app hosted on herouku sends a 503 error, heroku logs shown

Tags: reactjs, heroku

My app was running fine until yesterday when I encountered the 503 error from heroku. This is some kind of memory problem? is  my app too big?

Following are the logs:

```
2-10-25T05:51:04.417757+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-10-25T05:51:06.344304+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-25T05:51:06.344369+00:00 app[web.1]: > antonio@0.1.0 start
2022-10-25T05:51:06.344369+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2022-10-25T05:51:06.344369+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-25T05:51:08.523848+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:29) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
2022-10-25T05:51:08.523864+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
2022-10-25T05:51:08.524188+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:29) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
2022-10-25T05:51:08.601157+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-10-25T05:51:08.866454+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2022-10-25T05:51:08.866482+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-25T05:51:21.097850+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-25T05:51:21.097866+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- Last few GCs --->
2022-10-25T05:51:21.097866+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-25T05:51:21.097869+00:00 app[web.1]: [29:0x625e1f0]    14387 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 250.8 (258.4) -> 250.1 (258.9) MB, 248.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.185, current mu = 0.017) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed
2022-10-25T05:51:21.097869+00:00 app[web.1]: [29:0x625e1f0]    14647 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 251.3 (258.9) -> 250.6 (259.4) MB, 255.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.105, current mu = 0.018) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed
2022-10-25T05:51:21.097869+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-25T05:51:21.097874+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-25T05:51:21.097874+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
2022-10-25T05:51:21.097874+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-25T05:51:21.097876+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2022-10-25T05:51:21.098583+00:00 app[web.1]: 1: 0xb6e4e0 node::Abort() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-10-25T05:51:21.099109+00:00 app[web.1]: 2: 0xa7e632  [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-10-25T05:51:21.099688+00:00 app[web.1]: 3: 0xd47d90 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-10-25T05:51:21.100287+00:00 app[web.1]: 4: 0xd48137 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-10-25T05:51:21.100953+00:00 app[web.1]: 5: 0xf254f5  [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-10-25T05:51:21.101602+00:00 app[web.1]: 6: 0xf379dd v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-10-25T05:51:21.102240+00:00 app[web.1]: 7: 0xf120de v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-10-25T05:51:21.102880+00:00 app[web.1]: 8: 0xf134a7 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-10-25T05:51:21.103511+00:00 app[web.1]: 9: 0xef467a v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2-10-25T05:51:21.104314+00:00 app[web.1]: 10: 0x12b7c1f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-10-25T05:51:21.105155+00:00 app[web.1]: 11: 0x16e9879  [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-10-25T05:51:21.137715+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=antoniofront.herokuapp.com request_id=c860d338-4903-4172-88b7-5254593492f6 fwd="37.245.58.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12035ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-10-25T05:51:21.282660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: Don't start the local server in Heroku, you need to build the app using `npm run build`

Comment: @Abdulmuhaymin   Oh okay I am new to heroku, can you tell me how I can do that? Is there some setting that I must set?

Comment: Are you using Heroku CLI to push?

Comment: yes im using the git push heroku master command.

Comment: @Abdulmuhaymin hi could you please answer to this?

Comment: Do you have a backend or only the frontend? because you need a server to serve your frontend or if you only have a frontend then there are buildpacks in Heroku to serve static files.

Comment: @Abdulmuhaymin I have my react app hosted on separately from my django backend

Comment: It's better to serve the frontend from the same backend (Django) but if you want Heroku to serve the frontend only you need to rename index.html to index.php